# GUID to Hex Conversion Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, type-conversion, hex, guid

I have an excel of Millions of GUIDs in a column in Excel.
I want to convert it to HEX. Please advise the best way possible to do so.

if there is any formula for this, that would be awesome.

Sample data: 7330F811-F47F-41BC-A4FF-E792D073F41F
Expected output in HEX: 11f830737ff4bc41a4ffe792d073f41f

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 you could do:

```
=LET( GUID, C3,
            tmpGUID, REDUCE(GUID,{"{","-","}"},LAMBDA(t,o,SUBSTITUTE(t,o,""))),
            octetStr, MID(tmpGUID, 7, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 5, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 3, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 1, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 11, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 9, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 15, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 13, 2) & MID(tmpGUID, 17, LEN(tmpGUID)),
            LOWER(octetStr) )
```

Where C3 is the target GUID.

[image]